# dotnet core identity one to one relation between users

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have three main entities. "Student", "Teacher" and "Meeting".

I need to have something like this :

```
    public class Meeting
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime MeetingDate { get; set; }
        public AppUser Student { get; set; }
        public AppUser Teacher { get; set; }

    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        //...
    }

    public class Teacher
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        //...
    }
```

there are only one student and one teacher for each meeting.
so I need a meeting with two users (student and teacher) that both are registered users with different properties.

is this the correct way to implement the Meeting class?

thank you.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your comment. the teacher is not able to be a student at all. is there any comprehensive document to implement something like this?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.  So, we can you not set Meeting.Student = {the student chosen by use} and Meeting.Teacher = {the teacher chosen by user}?  What's not working for you?

Comment: @NeilW so simple, I need two totally separated users. even when I want to register them in the first place.

Comment: @Kalager, I was trying to be helpful.  If you're question is so simple then I would have expected some other responses by now.  More context is needed.

Comment: @NeilW thanks for your help.

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on what you need here. "How can I implement this" is not a very specific question. You tried something but you "think" it's not what you need. Why not? Please [edit] your question and elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for the updated question. It seems you have a good idea on how to proceed with those classes/models. Have you tried it out? How has it turned out for you?